# Why can't I protect questions?

Tags: support, protected-questions

So I'm a trusted user on [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/). Suddenly I can't protect questions anymore? Bug?

> [image]

I'm pretty sure this was working yesterday.

Comment: @Pat I'm pretty sure he has noticed the missing link, was not going to actually protect it. :)

Comment: I don't @PatrickHofman, Just noticed the button wasn't there...

Comment: @Oded why not make the link appear in gray and a tooltip explaining why it's disabled, same way for example we have for edit?

Answer (score 6):

From [Privileges > Protect questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions)

> ### Which questions can be protected?
>
> Any question at least a day old can be protected and unprotected by
> users that have the privilege.

And the question you showed is just 18 hours old, as I can see from the screenshot.

Only if you are a moderator, this restriction is removed.

Comment: "Only if you are a moderator, this restriction is removed" - really? How do  you know that?

Comment: @Sha you voted to close this question as dupe and... now it's time to read it :D

Comment: I did, and it's not saying in there that the one day restriction is not applied on moderators. (of course it's most likely correct :))

Answer (score 3):

> asked 18 hours ago

Here's your problem. You can only protect questions that are one or more days old. ([reference](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions))

Comment: ah, b*gger. Didn't know that!

Comment: @Liam FWIW you can try to appeal to powers that be (if there's sufficient evidence to support it) to enable site-specific feature of protecting without having to wait, like it was done [a while ago for Workplace.SE](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3060?m=13304581#13304581)